# Quick Exploding animation

Tags: animation, mesh, particles

I've made an animation that explodes a box and reveals text that's inside it.

However, I can't make it explode from the left->right. For some reason it starts from the right hand side of the cube.

I've tried to google it but cant find it. Also tried to check the settings but cant find it.

Some help would be awesome!

EDIT 1:

Hi. 30Mb max limit on that page.
So i uploaded the blend file here
https://forumfiles.com/j942T5Hdoe/killlah_wood_blend

Comment: Could you upload a picture of what you have so far and also the blender file so that we could take a look at what's going on?  You can upload blender files here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Edited first post

Answer (score 1):

select the exploding box then press:

<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>180</kbd> --> done!

- R = rotation
- Z = rotate on Z axis
- 180 = rotate 180 degree

Comment: Thx! Worked like a sharm!